# React Ionic Tabs nested Routes Animación no funciona

Tags: reactjs, ionic, ionic-framework, react-router-dom

He intentado de distintos modos crear rutas anidadas con tabs, la idea seria la siguiente:

- WelcomePage->LoginPage->HomePage(Tab)->RecipePage

El problema esta en la animacion de entrada a HomePage y tambien la de salida, En el caso de ir de WelcomePage a LoginPage si funciona, igualmente para ir hacia atras de RecipePage a HomePage.

Se que el asunto radica en IonRouterOutlet y Route, y como se organizan estos, pero he hecho las combinaciones que se me han ocurrido, y utilizando varias formas para renderizar el componente en el Route, como es la prop render, component, y tambien como children. Si alguien ha realizado algo parecido y ha conseguido algo optimo, o tal vez este pasando algo por alto, agradeceria la ayuda, gracias.

Este es mi App.tsx (resumido, tengo mas rutas ademas /signUp, unas 50 rutas):

```
      <IonApp>
        <IonReactRouter>
          <IonContent> //Este Content solo tiene sentido aca porque, el espacio en blanco 
                       //que remplaza la animación se vuelve negro, en blanco se ve mejor.
            <IonRouterOutlet>
              <Route path="/home"> //La ruta de las tabs
                <Home />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/signUp" exact>
                <SignUp />
              </Route>
             </IonRouterOutlet>
          </IonContent>
        </IonReactRouter>
      </IonApp>
```

Mi Home.tsx (4 rutas en total):

```
    <IonTabs>
      <IonRouterOutlet>
        <Route path="/home/search" exact>
          <Search />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/home/explore" exact>
          <Explore />
        </Route>
        <Redirect exact path="/home" to="/home/search" />
      </IonRouterOutlet>
      <IonTabBar slot="bottom" className="py-1">
        <IonTabButton tab="search" href="/home/search">
          <IonIcon icon={searchOutline} />
          <IonLabel>{textos["page_buscar"]}</IonLabel>
        </IonTabButton>
        <IonTabButton tab="explore" href="/home/explore">
          <IonIcon icon={navigateOutline} />
          <IonLabel>{textos["page_explorar"]}</IonLabel>
        </IonTabButton>
      </IonTabBar>
    </IonTabs>
```

- Una muestra mas grafica, se alcanza a apreciar una pantalla blanca, ahi es donde deberia
  estar la animación, esto es en android.

[image: Una muestra mas grafica]

- En iphone la animación de PageRecipesList(/recipes) a PageRecipe(/recipe) (no tabs):

[image: Iphone Bien]

- En iphone la animación de PageHomeSearch(Tab home/search) a
  PageRecipesList(/recipes):

[image: Iphone Mal]

- Si se quita el  que comente arriba se veria asi:

[image: Sin Content]

Gracias!